# PHP DOM HTML table manipulation

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to figure out why this piece of code isn't working. It takes HTML from another part of the code, takes the table out of it, creates another column and tries to move a td element to the row above in the newly created column.

The table imported:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Existing column1  | Existing column2   | Existing column3 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| A                 | B                 | C                 |
| D                 | E                 | F                 |
| G                                                         |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to try and make it look like this:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| Existing column1  | Existing column2  | Existing column3  | New column1 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| A                 | B                 | C                 |             |
| D                 | E                 | F                 | G           |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

So whenever a `td` element has the class `text-info`, it moves it up a `tr` and appends it to the last `Comment` column

My code so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();//Loads DOM document
$dom->loadHTML($str);//Loads HTML from a previously set variable
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tables = $xpath->query('//table[@class="behaviourtable table"]');//Get only table from HTML
$commsTable = '';
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $commsTable .=  $dom->saveXML($table);
}

$commsHTML = new DOMDocument();
$commsHTML->loadHTML($commsTable);

$tr = $commsHTML->getElementsByTagName('tr');


$th = $commsHTML->createElement('th', 'Comment');
$tr->item(0)->appendChild($th);

$xpathcomms = new DOMXPath($commsHTML);
$comments = $xpathcomms->query('//td[@class="text-info"]');
if($comments->length > 0){
    echo "if running";
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $parent = $comment->parentNode;
$parent->appendChild($comment);
$commsHTML->saveXML($parent);
}

}


echo $commsHTML->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I think `$tables` hasn't any result. Because class name can't contain space but you used `[@class="behaviourtable table"]`

Comment: @Mohammad The code works up until the `$xpathcomms = new DOMXPath($commsHTML);` line. The `$tables`, definitely returns the HTML table with the new column `Comments`.

Comment: Does php return any error?

Comment: @Mohammad No error is given by PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you append the `td` to it's original parent node (which does nothing), while what you are actually wanna do is get the parent (`tr`), go to it's previous sibling (prev `tr`) and append the `td` to that `tr`:

```
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $parent = $comment->parentNode;
    $parent->previousSibling->appendChild($comment);
}
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
$str = <<<END
<table class="behaviourtable table">
    <tr>
        <th>Existing column1</th>
        <th>Existing column2</th>
        <th>Existing column3</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td class="text-info">G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
END;

$dom = new DOMDocument();//Loads DOM document
$dom->loadHTML($str);//Loads HTML from a previously set variable
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tables = $xpath->query('//table[@class="behaviourtable table"]');//Get only table from HTML
$commsTable = '';
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $commsTable .=  $dom->saveXML($table);
}

$commsHTML = new DOMDocument();
$commsHTML->loadHTML($commsTable);

$tr = $commsHTML->getElementsByTagName('tr');


$th = $commsHTML->createElement('th', 'Comment');
$tr->item(0)->appendChild($th);

$xpathcomms = new DOMXPath($commsHTML);
$comments = $xpathcomms->query('//td[@class="text-info"]');
if($comments->length > 0){
    foreach($comments as $comment){
        $parent = $comment->parentNode;
        $parent->previousSibling->appendChild($comment);
    }
}

echo $commsHTML->saveHTML();
```

Check this working example:
https://3v4l.org/FZkNE